# How to improve sample representativeness for longitudinal data collected via an online platform?

Tags: bias, growth-model, weighted-sampling, selection-bias, representative

I am working with a longitudinal dataset exploring cognitive ageing (e.g., memory performance over time). Participants complete the study annually. Inclusion criteria for this study are 1) UK resident, 2) Aged 50 years or older, 3) no dementia diagnosis at baseline.

The study is open to anyone meeting these criteria and is administered online. This means that the sample is not representative of the target population (i.e., UK residents aged 50 or over without dementia diagnosis at baseline). There is also attrition and missing data at the annual follow-ups.

Note that there is no nationally representative data that includes information on dementia diagnosis. Therefore it would be difficult to estimate an accurate reference for our target population.

I plan to run latent growth curve models to assess whether a specific predictor variable is associated with baseline cognition or change in cognition over time.

**Please can people advise methods that could be used to correct for participation bias, and whether this is impacted by missing data?**

Note that to address missing data I had planned to implement the approach described by Zinn & Gnambs (2018) whereby different models are tested that assume different mechanisms of missingness...

***References***

Zinn, S., & Gnambs, T. (2018). Modeling competence development in the presence of selection bias. Behavior research methods, 50, 2426-2441.